# using Base64 HMAC SHA1 in Java not getting expected results

Tags: java, base64, hmacsha1

I´m trying to use HMAC SHA1 one way algorithm

This is my code

```
@Test
public void encodeTest() {

    String HMAC_SHA1_ALGORITHM = "HmacSHA1";
    String EXPECTED_BASE_64 = "g9OrJ8pQNYprnXuBPFXcirrqpxE=";

    String text = "encodeme";
    String result;

    try {
        SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(
                "MSbN2crsrdTEsLetTixpV46q+fTZotdZjwoEpO62vYk=".getBytes(),
                HMAC_SHA1_ALGORITHM);
        // Get an hmac_sha1 Mac instance and initialise with the signing key
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_SHA1_ALGORITHM);
        mac.init(signingKey);
        // Compute the hmac
        byte[] rawHmac = mac.doFinal(text.getBytes());
        // Convert raw bytes to Hex
        byte[] hexBytes = new Hex().encode(rawHmac);
        // Covert array of Hex bytes to a String

        result = new String(hexBytes, "ISO-8859-1");
        // Ok, this matches with the web
        System.out.println("HEX:" + result);

        String encodedBase64 = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(hexBytes));
        System.out.println("BASE64:" + encodedBase64);

        // In the web i get a smaller chain, why?
        System.out.println("EXPECTED BASE64:" + EXPECTED_BASE_64);
        Assert.assertEquals(EXPECTED_BASE_64, encodedBase64);

    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Output is

HEX:83d3ab27ca50358a6b9d7b813c55dc8abaeaa711
BASE64:ODNkM2FiMjdjYTUwMzU4YTZiOWQ3YjgxM2M1NWRjOGFiYWVhYTcxMQ==

EXPECTED BASE64:g9OrJ8pQNYprnXuBPFXcirrqpxE=

I defined my expectations using these online sites

http://hash.online-convert.com/sha1-generator

text=encodeme

using shared secret key

key=MSbN2crsrdTEsLetTixpV46q+fTZotdZjwoEpO62vYk=

The results I get are slightly different

hex: 83d3ab27ca50358a6b9d7b813c55dc8abaeaa711
HEX: 83D3AB27CA50358A6B9D7B813C55DC8ABAEAA711
h:e:x: 83:d3:ab:27:ca:50:35:8a:6b:9d:7b:81:3c:55:dc:8a:ba:ea:a7:11
base64: g9OrJ8pQNYprnXuBPFXcirrqpxE=

As you see the hex output matches 100%, however the base64 output does not match at all

To verify that the problem was not in that site I went to another one
just to do encode a hex string using base64 and again I got the same results...

http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php?lang=en

Anyone have an idea why this is happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you want to base64 encode the hex bytes, and not the `rawHmac`?

Comment: I added String encodedRawMacBase64 = new String(
     Base64.encodeBase64(rawHmac));
   System.out.println("RAW BASE64:" + encodedRawMacBase64);     and YES I got the result i wanted.  You saved me scratching my head. Brilliant!